# How can I solve the problem on the segment tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I have an array a[0..n - 1]. I have 2 types operations:

1. sum l r:
   sum = a[l] * 1 + a[l+1] * 2 + ... + a[r] * (r - l)
2. update index value: a[index] = value

How can I modify standart sum segment tree for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a second segment tree for sums of the array `b`, where `b[i] = (i+1) * a[i]`. Then, setting `a[index] = value` should also update the second segment tree with `b[index] = value * (index + 1)`.

To calculate the sum you want, given the ability to query the normal subarray sums of `a` and `b`:

```
special_sum(l, r) = a[l] * 1 + a[l+1] * 2 + ... + a[r] * (r - l)
can be rewritten as:

(l+1) * a[l] + (l+2) * a[l+1] + ... + (r) * a[r]
- l * (a[l] + a[l+1] + ... + a[r])

which becomes

b[l] + b[l+1] + ... + b[r]
- l * (a[l] + a[l+1] + ... + a[r])
```

Comment: @Alex If this completely answered your question, be sure to eventually ‘accept’ this answer (or another answer) so it gets marked as solved.